# A Special Case of Set Cover Problem: Covering Nodes of Tree using Paths

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, set-cover

Let $U$ be the set of elements and $S$ be the subset collections. There exists a tree $T$ that each node is corresponding to an element in $U$. And for every subset $s$ in $S$, $V(T) \bigcap s $ is a path of T.

And I want to find a minimum set $Z$, where $Z \subset S$, and $\forall u \in U, \exists z \in Z$ s.t $u \in z$.

---

This problem can also be rephrased to giving a tree with a set of paths $P$ on the tree, and I want to select a minimal set of paths subset to $P$ that covers each node on that tree at least once.

Can this be done in polynomial time?

Comment: I might rephrase the question: You have a tree with a given set of paths $P$ on that tree.  You want to select a minimal set of nodes that covers each path at least once.  Is that accurate?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I can rephrase this to: I have a tree with a set of paths $P$ on the tree, and I want to select a minimal set of paths subset to $P$ that cover each node on that tree at least once.

Comment: What is your question?  I don't see a question here.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about your situation.  A question usually ends in "?".  We expect you to state your question in the body of the post.  The title should be a short summary. The body of the post needs to make sense on its own. Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what you are asking. Don't put clarifications in the comments -- revise the question so it contains all relevant information, and people don't need to read the comments to understand what is being asked.